# Complex number simplifications

Tags: simplifying-expressions, complex

My Mathematica notebook is not simplifying some expressions which do look trivial. I mean that one of my outputs contains:

```
Sqrt[Im[z1]^2 - 2 Im[z1] Im[z2] + Im[z2]^2 + (Re[z1] - Re[z2])^2]
```

which is nothing but

```
Abs[z1-z2]
```

I guess it does not simpligy because of the non analyticity of `Re` or `Im` or the ambiguity in `Sqrt` on the complex plane but is there a way to force Mathematica do do such replacements? That would help me a lot as it appears in many places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sqrt[Im[z1]^2 - 2 Im[z1] Im[z2] + Im[z2]^2 + (Re[z1] - Re[z2])^2] // 
  ComplexExpand // Simplify

(*  ((z1 - z2)^4)^(1/4)   *)
```

Have fun!

Comment: Thanks for the input, indeed I had already met that `ComplexExpand` function.

Comment: @Learning is a mess Of course, this is the first choice, when doing with complex numbers.